# Why are eigenvector computations in matlab and python not matching?

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, scipy

Matlab:

```
m1 = [ 333.33333333  83.33333333   0. ;  83.33333333 333.33333333  83.33333333 ;  0.   3.33333333 166.66666667]
k1 = [ 800. -400.    0.; -400.  800. -400.;   0. -400.  400.]
[vec, val] = eig(m1, k1)

vec =

   -0.0106   -0.0289    0.0394
    0.0183   -0.0000    0.0683
   -0.0211    0.0289    0.0789
```

python:

```
import scipy
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array[[333.33333333,  83.33333333,  0.], [ 83.33333333, 333.33333333, 83.33333333], [0., 83.33333333, 166.66666667]]
k1 = np.array[[800., -400.,  0.], [-400.,  800., -400.], [0., -400.,  400.]]
val, vec = scipy.linalg.eig(m1, k1)

vec = 
[[ 3.53553391e-01, -7.07106781e-01,  3.53553391e-01], 
[ 6.12372436e-01,  1.88119544e-16, -6.12372436e-01], 
[ 7.07106781e-01,  7.07106781e-01,  7.07106781e-01]]
```

So matlab and python eigenvectors `vec` are not matching. Matlab [document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) says

> [V,D] = eig(A,B) returns diagonal matrix D of generalized eigenvalues
> and full matrix V whose columns are the corresponding right
> eigenvectors, so that `A*V = B*V*D`.

and `m1 * vec = k1 * vec * val` satisfies for matlab output but not for python output. How can I get similar eigenvectors as given by matlab using python, numpy?

Comment: I think this difference has been discussed in previous SO, though I haven't paid much attention.  Looks like vectors for both a columns, but is the normalization the same?  How about order?  `np.linalg.eig` seems to have a more complete docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eigenvectors are not unique; if `x` is an eigenvector, then `a * x` is still an eigenvector for any nonzero scalar `a`.

Look at the two results from python and matlab; the first column of `vec` from matlab looks like a scaled version of the third column of `vec` from python. The second column from matlab seems to be a scaled version of the second column from python (recall `1.88119544e-16` is almost zero). The third column corresponds to the first column. So my guess is that `val` from matlab is a reversed version of `val` from python; I can't verify this because I don't have matlab right now, but you can verify this.

Also in python, remember `*` is element-wise multiplication (i.e., `.*` in matlab). You can use `@` for matrix multiplication.

```py
import scipy.linalg
import numpy as np
m1 = np.array([[333.33333333,  83.33333333,  0.], [ 83.33333333, 333.33333333, 83.33333333], [0., 83.33333333, 166.66666667]])
k1 = np.array([[800., -400.,  0.], [-400.,  800., -400.], [0., -400.,  400.]])
val, vec = scipy.linalg.eig(m1, k1)

print(m1 @ vec)
print(k1 @ vec * val)
```

As you can see in the following output, we have the same output (the imaginary part is `0.j`, so you can ignore that).

Output:

```
[[ 1.68882167e+02 -2.35702260e+02  6.68200939e+01]
 [ 2.92512493e+02 -3.14270210e-09 -1.15735798e+02]
 [ 1.68882167e+02  1.17851130e+02  6.68200939e+01]]
[[ 1.68882167e+02+0.j -2.35702260e+02+0.j  6.68200939e+01+0.j]
 [ 2.92512493e+02+0.j -3.14263578e-09+0.j -1.15735798e+02+0.j]
 [ 1.68882167e+02+0.j  1.17851130e+02+0.j  6.68200939e+01+0.j]]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of, if your model is a spring-mass system with `m1` mass matrix and `k1` stiffness matrix, you should fix your matlab eig call as

`[vec, val] = eig(k1, m1)`

then, it is already said above that eigenvectors are not unique, so you can normalize them with any value you want. For example, you can normalize each eigen vector to be normalized by its maximum value so that each vector would have a maximum vector value of 1.0. Matlab does 2-norm normalization. scipy probably does a different normalization. You can still get the results of matlab. Check for the eigen vectors and 2-norm normalization in google, you can find how to get to that. I don't recall it now, but I have done it before.
Also, you probably already have it correct in your code, but above in your question you forgot parenthesis after `np.array` that I fixed.